# Access key bindings for a major mode

Tags: key-bindings, doom

Running Doom Emacs 3.0 on Emacs 28.

I have installed todotxt.el using:

```
(package! todotxt)
```

in `packages.el`.

When I Open my todo.txt file and `M-x todotxt-mode`, `sPC h b m` shows all the keybindings available. But none of these work when I try them on a file.

For instance, 'i' is supposed to hide complete tasks but it still switches to insert mode.

How do I access the major mode keybindings?

Comment: This is unclear, what do you mean by "try them on a file"? You already have a file open and the major mode active, according to what you write. How is "try them on a file" different?

Comment: Evil mode is a minor mode, thus its priority is higher than a major mode like `todotxt-mode`. Spacemacs has its way (I'm not confident enough to say what or how though) to enable less evil keybindings for certain major modes, for instance `Info-mode`, `compilation-mode`, `message-mode`, etc. I believe doom emacs also have similar mechanisms. Perhaps you'll have better luck digging through doom documentation or ask on a doom specific user forum. Or you can unbind evil one by one or locally bind evil to `todotxt` related commands, but that's tedious and I wouldn't call that a proper solution.